# Is there any function in google sheets by which we can remove some numbers in google sheets?

Tags: filter, formula, spreadsheet

Suppose there is a sheet in which there are 100 contact numbers and I want to bring the numbers in different google sheets after removing selected numbers. How can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

So you want to replace the "the old numbers" with "New numbers for the selected contacts. Is in't it???

Then the solution is vlookup.
- Remove the selected numbers
- Sort it Ascending order based on the contact numbers column, so that you will get all the blank spaces bottom of the dataset.
- Now you can replace/fill the blank places by using vlookup fuction.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).